# What is the need for a primitive when using a transient property?

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is it?

I'm not sure I quite understand what this does.

```
- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier {

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveSectionIdentifier];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    if (!tmp) {

        tmp = @"bananas";

        [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:tmp];
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

How come I need this **primitiveSectionIdentifier**?

Ultimately, I'm using a example project from Apple's documentation to create a section identifier, to use with my NSFetchedResultsController.

While this does work. I am saying to myself that,

"**sectionIdentifier**" will be accessed,
then I'm setting "**tmp**" to **primitiveSectionIdentifier**. But primitiveSectionIdentifier has nothing there at this point!! Does it?

I then say I did access "**sectionIdentifier**". But I can't see how that happened between "Will" and "Did"!

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: if `setSectionIdentifier` has been previously called, calling `-primitiveSectionIdentifier` will return a value. This is basically saying "is `sectionIdentifier` set to a value? if not, set it to 'bananas'". Is that what you are asking?

Comment: To some extent, yes. I was having trouble understanding the need for the primitive and it's purpose. Making everything much more confusing. Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[self primitiveSectionIdentifier]` is a so-called "primitive accessor" (see the Glossary of the Core Data Programming Guide). That is the function that actually fetches the value of the "sectionIdentifier" from the persistent store. The function is automatically created by the Core Data runtime.

`willAccessValueForKey` and `didAccessValueForKey` are "notification methods". According to the documentation, they are used for key-value observing, maintaining inverse relationships and so on.

So the pattern is:

1. Tell everybody that you are going to read a value.
2. Read the value.
3. Tell everybody that you have read the value.

Comment: Took me a couple of days. But I get it now. I also was missing the proper terms. Thank you very much Sir.